# MySQL insert using continuous number

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert

I'm copying a row in a table using this statement:

```
insert into Buyer (
    version, creationDate, password, token, username, zip, city, lastname, firstname, preferredLanguage_id, title_id, contactEmail_id, active
) select
    version, creationDate, password, token, "loadtest_1@example.com", zip, city, lastname, firstname, preferredLanguage_id, title_id, contactEmail_id, active
from Buyer where username="developer_de@example.com";
```

Only thing I change is the username/email. Now the number in the new username to be inserted, "loadtest_1@example.com", should increment every time. So the second should be loadtest_2..., loadtest_3 and so on. I don't really care at what number it starts as long as it's continuous, so taking the ID of the newly inserted row or the like would be totally okay.

Extra kudos for ideas on how to actually create a batch of these inserts so I don't have to run it X times.

Comment: How about a stored procedure that takes a starting number & number of times to repeat - within the stored procedure you update the name string within a for loop.

Comment: At the time of my reply Rahul had only given the UPDATE solution - which I commented on - the edit must have been done at the same time.:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are selecting and inserting to same table and only change is `username`. what I see is you need a `UPDATE` statement rather like

```
update Buyer set username = 'loadtest_1@example.com'
where username="developer_de@example.com";
```

If it's test and you do really want to insert test data saying `loadtest_1@example.com .. loadtest_100@example.com` then you can use a `while` loop like

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_inserttestdata(total INT)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE counter INT;
DECLARE uname varchar(20);

   SET counter = 1;

   label1: WHILE counter <= total DO

    SET uname = concat('loadtest_', counter, '@example.com');     

   insert into Buyer (
    version, creationDate, password, token, username, zip, city, lastname, 
    firstname, preferredLanguage_id, title_id, contactEmail_id, active) 
   select version, creationDate, password, token, uname, zip, city, lastname, firstname, 
   preferredLanguage_id, title_id, contactEmail_id, active
   from Buyer where username="developer_de@example.com";

   SET counter = counter + 1;

   END WHILE label1;
END
```

Then call the procedure saying

```
CALL usp_inserttestdata 1000
```

Comment: Updating an existing row and copying is not the same

Comment: Judging by the new name - I am guessing OP wants to add X number of new users, rather than update a single user X number of times.

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak, mind checking the edit in answer again!

Comment: It definately looks like what I want. Only... is there something missing? Because my mysql client tells me that DECLARE is not allowed at that position. Do I need a procedure or something around that code?

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak, yes it's just the main code logic. You need to wrap it around a `begin .. end` block which should inside a procedure.

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak, OK ... you want complete. check edit in few seconds.

Comment: Nice! I just put the procedure around it while your edit came in. It all works except the concat() only taking the first two args into account. But I'll figure out that one myself. Thanks!

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak, you can as well use string concatenation operator `+`  other than `concat()` string method.

Comment: + causes the result to be the number only, even if I cast it to char.

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak, change that line to `concat('loadtest_', cast(counter as varchar), '@example.com')`

Comment: Found the problem. uname was defined as VARCHAR(20)... :-D

Comment: Yeah, I meant varchar. Still 20 was not enough for the whole email address. Nevermind, everything works now thanks to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AFTER Trigger` `ON INSERT` operation to achive your goal. In the body of this trigger update email and set corresponding value depends on auto increment id value.